# Add number of line with awk

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

i would to know how can i edit my csv file to add first column with name 'linenumber' and iterate through each line and insert the number of the line in this column ?

Something like that

```
TEST TEST2 TEST3
valu value value
```

To that

```
linenumber TEST TEST2 TEST3
1          valu value value
```

Thanks in advance

Stoufiler

Answer (score 1):

Following awk should help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "linenumber",$0;next} {print FNR-1,$0}'   Input_file
```

In case you need to edit the Input_file itself then following may help you.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "linenumber",$0;next} {print FNR-1,$0}'  OFS=","  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Comment: it's work well but it's not a new column in fact they add the number and the valu :/

Comment: @Stoufiler, could you please explain your statement above, sorry didn't get it.

Comment: sorry i'm not english :) the problem is now the file contain the same number of column but the first one is concatenate so the title of the first column is `linenumber TEST` and no `linenumber | TEST`

Comment: @RavinderSingth13 Thanks, I'm going to try to explain myself correctly, Actually when I use the command you passed me the file is well modified but the linenumer column is not added, it is added to the first one so that the first one column equals linenumber + titleofthenextcolumn

Comment: @RavinderSingth13 It doesn't it make the same thing, i publish a codeshare for showing you y problem [link]https://codeshare.io/Gbw3xV

Comment: when i use this command, `awk 'FNR==1{print "linenumber,",$0;next} {print FNR-1",",$0}' input.csv > output.csv` it works but i have a space between coma after linenumber and the next column, how can i fix that ?

Comment: @Stoufiler You have to modify the description and state that you have a comma separated input file.

Comment: i modify like that `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}FNR==1{print "linenumber,",$0;next} {print FNR-1",",$0}' input.csv > output.csv` and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: You have to define the output delimiter as comma: `awk 'FNR==1{print "linenumber,"$0;next} {OFS=","; print FNR-1,$0}' input.csv`

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer, it's that

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "linenumber,"$0;next} {print FNR-1,$0}' OFS="," input.csv > output.csv
```

thanks for all

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i'm sorry to come back a new time but i would like to know how i can inverse the process so remove the first column ? :)

Comment: Sure, please edit your post or open a thread and let me know then on same,

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it's ok this is the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904805/delete-first-column-of-csv-file