# Delete first column of csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to know how i can delete the first column of a csv file with awk or sed

Something like this :

```
FIRST,SECOND,THIRD
```

To something like that

```
SECOND,THIRD
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Following awk will be helping you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/[^,]*/,"");sub(/,/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

Following sed may also help you in same.

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\2/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk code here.
{
  sub(/[^,]*/,"")     ##Using sub for substituting everything till 1st occurence of comma(,) with NULL.
  sub(/,/,"")         ##Using sub for substituting comma with NULL in current line.
}
1                     ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'   Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: 2 `sub` calls can be combined into one by `sub(/[^,]*,/,"")`

Comment: Why does'nt  the command   sub(/,/,"")  remove all the comma?

Comment: Because it's sub its designed to remove only 1 comma, on other hand gsub us for Global substitution which can remove all commas.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` :  `^[^,]+,` regex represent the first column including the first comma. `^` means start of the line, `[^,]+,` means anything one or more times but a comma sign followed by a comma.

you can use `-i` with `sed` to make changes in file if needed.

```
sed -r 's/^[^,]+,//' input
SECOND,THIRD
```

Comment: Without the -r option : sed 's/^[^,]*,//' input

Comment: This one worked for me, sed 's/[^,]*,//'

Answer (score 1):

With Sed

```
sed -i -r 's@^\w+,@@g' test.csv
```

Grab the begin of the line ^, every character class [A-Za-z0-9] and also underscore until we found comma and replace with nothing.
Adding g after delimiters you can do a global substitution.

Comment: I doubt if this will give the correct answer. `.*` means greedy match so you are going to replace till last comma.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i have updated the code.

Comment: This has been marked as low-quality for length and content. Would you mind elaborating a bit on your suggested command. What are the switches for? ...

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk**

```
$awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1=$2; $2=$3; NF--;}1' file
SECOND,THIRD
```